# A collection $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ so that $\sup_{\alpha \in A} f_{\alpha}(x)$ is finite and non-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Background**

Give an example of a collection of measurable non-negative functions $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ such that if $g$ is defined by $g(x)=\sup_{\alpha \in A} f_{\alpha}(x)$, then $g$ is finite for all values of $x$ but $g$ is non-measurable. ($A$ is allowed to be uncountable.

**Attempt**

Let $A$ be the Vitali set. Then $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable. For each $\alpha \in A$, let $$f_{\alpha}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x=\alpha \\ 0 &\mbox{if } x \neq \alpha \end{cases}.$$
Then for each $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\{x:f_{\alpha}(x)>\beta\}\in \{\varnothing, \{\alpha\},\mathbb{R}\},$$ so $f_\alpha$ is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue $\sigma-$ algebra. However, $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } x\in A \\ 0 &\mbox{if } x \not\in A \end{cases},$$ which is finite and non-measurable since $\{x:g(x)>0\}=A.$

**Question**

Is my example correct? Specifically, is more work required to show that $g$ turns out to be as I have claimed?

Comment: The statement immediately following the definition of $f_\alpha$ isn’t quite right. What you mean is that for each $\beta\in\Bbb R$, $$\{x\in\Bbb R:f_\alpha(x)>\beta\}\in\big\{\varnothing,\Bbb R,\{\alpha\}\big\}\;.$$ Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: your functions $f_\alpha$ and $g$ are correct and solve the problem. however, i do not know, what you mean with $\{x:f_{\alpha}(x)>\beta\}=\{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}, \alpha\}$.

Comment: @supinf I just made an edit...is it now correct?

Comment: Not quite: the possibilities are $\varnothing$, $\Bbb R$, and $\{\alpha\}$. Note that $\{x:f_\alpha(x)>\beta\}$ is a set of real numbers, but $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\Bbb R\}$ are not, so they can’t be equal to $\{x:f_\alpha(x)>\beta\}$.

Comment: One thing I would like to add that is small, but you say " $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with Lebesgue measure". There are a few things wrong with this statement. First, is this the domain or range? (I'm assuming both, so it's not a big deal). More importantly however, is that measurability has nothing to do with what MEASURE is on the space, it has to do with what $\sigma$ algebra is on the space. I'm assuming you mean Borel $\sigma$ algebra?

Comment: Thank-you guys so much for the feedback, it's exactly what I needed. I edited it again. @avid19 is this the proper way to talk about function measurability?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct except specifying in more detail about
$$\{x:f_{\alpha}(x)>\beta\}\in \{\varnothing, \{\alpha\},\mathbb{R}\}$$
like 
$$
\{x:f_{\alpha}(x)>\beta\}=\begin{cases} 
\varnothing & \text{ if } \beta\geqslant1 
\\ 
\{\alpha\} & \text{ if } 0\leqslant\beta<1
\\
\mathbb{R} & \text{ if } \beta<0
\end{cases}
$$